# how to extract only audio files and put them in an arrayList

Tags: audio, java

I am writing a program where i want all my audio files (.mp3,.wav etc ) files in an arrayList
my code looks like this:

```
public class FileTest
{

    public ArrayList<File> list(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files)
    {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isFile() **&& (if the file is an audio file)**) {
                files.add(file);
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                list(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
            }

        }

        return files;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileTest fileTest = new FileTest();

        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

        files = fileTest.list("/media/kumuda/D804C38204C361DC/Program Files",files);

        for(File file : files)
        {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to check if the file is an audio file before adding it to my arraylist.
I searched for api's and came across Apache Tika library. 
but i am not getting how it exactly works.
Please can anyone help me ?

Comment: So the question is only how to decide whether a file is an audio file, correct?

Comment: Are you stuck with Java 6? If no, you should try and use [`Files.walkFileTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) and make an appropriate visitor

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you would do that using `Files`.

First, create a `FileVisitor`. Extend `SimpleFileVisitor` since it is enough for your needs:

```
public final class AudioFileCollector
    extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
{
    private final List<Path> fileList;

    public AudioFileCollector(final List<Path> fileList)
    {
        this.fileList = fileList;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
        throws IOException
    {
        // We know this is a regular file here, so now we just need to check the type
        switch (Files.probeContentType(file)) {
            case "audio/x-wav": // wav file
            case "audio/mpeg":  // mp3
                fileList.add(file);
            default:
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e)
        throws IOException
    {
        if (e != null)
            throw e;
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
```

Then walk your directory with this visitor:

```
final Path baseDir = Paths.get("...");
final List<Path> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
final FileVisitor<Path> collector = new AudioFileCollector(fileList);

Files.walkFileTree(baseDir, collector);
```

Done!

Note the use of `Files.probeContentType()`.

---

Solution with Java 8 (I guess it could be better):

```
public final class Main
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final List<String> extensions = Arrays.asList(".mp3", ".wav");
        final Path start = Paths.get("...");

        Files.walk(start).map(Object::toString)
            .filter(s -> extensions.stream().anyMatch(s::endsWith))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

If you want to collect in a list, replace `.forEach()` with `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: This is a very good solution! Although one shouldn't always rely on a MIME type (when it comes to security etc.), in this case it's just perfect - fast and efficient. Opening each file and validating it would be insanely slow. Thanks for inspirational solution!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use ragex and check if the filename matches a pattern. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Something like

```
if( Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+.mp3",file) || Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+.wav",file) )     
{
// your code here
}
```